How to convert a relative commit reference to a SHA?
Let's assume I have an SHA from let's say SHA=${{ github.ref }} and a relative described commit like ${SHA}^1, how can I convert this to a "new" SHA without the relative "path" part?
In file system APIs, I would call a function like resolve() to convert all relative parts to a fully absolute path.
Unfortunately, I need a resolved SHA for the API I'm using. It doesn't accept relative commit descriptions as inputs, just bare SHAs.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+previous+commit+sha

git rev-parse "${SHA}^1"
